# Search for a string in HTML source rendered page with PHP

Tags: php, html, string-parsing

I have a rendered page written in PHP that output this code:

```
    <html>
    <body>
   random code 

    <u>Hello everyone</u>

   random code    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now I need to check if the page contains the string 'Hello everyone' and to something when found, or do nothing when not found. The page rendered is located in the same server.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more background on what you want to achieve? It's doesn't make much sense to render a page and then parse it again.

Comment: E-commerce content that change dinamically and I want to hide the left and right column in cart page and checkout process. All these pages have an HTML tag <u>Checkout steps</u>. I want identify that pages through this tag and do not load columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try -

```
$page_source=file_get_contents("page_url"); //or use curl

if(preg_match("/Hello everyone/i",$page_source)){
    //do something
}
else{
    //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using jQuery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
random code 
<u>Hello everyone</u>
random code 
</body>
</html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url="filecont.php"//THE PHP FILE LOCATION
$.post(url, function(data) {
  var count = data.match(/Hello everyone/g); 
  if(count.length<=1){//If its in the same file, because in .match(/Hello everyone/g); already exist
    alert("NOT FOUND");
  }
  else{
    alert("YEAH!, FOUND");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: The file_get_contents output the raw index.php file, not the generated html so the search will make no effect

Comment: This should work just fine, unless the render content changes dynamicly (using javascript, or the same PHP), in that case an ajax function would be better, because only reads the rendered content

Comment: Yes. The content change dinamically using both javascript and same PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$isexist = strpos($the_page_text, "Hello everyone");
```

Comment: $the_page_text it is the text of your page it is rendered right? So it must be a variable?

Comment: No sorry, it's not a variable. It is simple the html source code rendered.

Comment: html source rendered using curl?

Comment: No, it's the output of 'index.php' page. I have to search inside the <body> </body> tags "after" rendered.

Comment: then do this $content = file_get_contents("index.php"); $isexist = strpos($the_page_text, "Hello everyone");